# Core Plot: NSAssert exception in CPTConstraintsFixed: `LowerBound must be less than or equal to upperBound`

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I am getting an `NSAssert` exception in Core Plot's `positionForLowerBound:lowerBound upperBound:` method in the class `CPTConstraintsFixed.m`:

> [_CPTConstraintsFixed positionForLowerBound:upperBound:],
>   /Users/AR/Downloads/core-plot/framework/Source/_CPTConstraintsFixed.m:79

The crash occurs in the code line with the assertion:`lowerBound must be less than or equal to upperBound`.

This is my stack trace:

[image]

I am using a bar chart with the following setup:

```
x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
relativePlotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange
    plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(xAxisStart)
    length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(xAxisLength)];
```

The values I am supplying for `xAxisLength = 6` and for `xAxisStart = -0.5`.

Do you have any suggestion on what could be the cause for this error?

Thank you!

Comment: As it says - Your Lower bound (0.0) should be <= -0.5. Hope you figure it out now.  :)

Comment: @Reno, my code works 95% of the time with this parameters. The error message says that the `upper bound` (e.g.`6`) must be `above the lower bound` (e.g. `-0.5`). I don't see anything wrong with my values.

Comment: Can you pass lower bound in xAxisStart as 0.0 instead of -0.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to some y-values: Some of them were the `infinite` result of a floating point division. I check now for infinity and replace those values with `[NSNull null]`values.